# I have a problem initializing a variable connected to a struct array

Tags: c

I have this project where I have to create a struct array with C language for students' data, and I can't seem to get past this warning by my variable arr_student. The warning says that I have not initialized the variable, and whenever I try to debug it the IDE says that it has a memory error involving where it goes. I want to be able to declare it and use it as a way to get to the variables created in my struct array. If anyone knows what I could be missing, that would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define numero 2                      //This number is the limiter for the number of students

struct Student 
{                                     //Define struct array with student information
    char id[50];
    char gpa[50];
    char address[50];
    char phone_number[50];
    char first_name[50];
    char last_name[50];
};

int main(struct Student arr_student[numero])
{
    int i;                            //Counter
    char tempvalue[50];               //Temporary variable to store data in the array
    char search[50];                  //Search value input by user
    int result = 1;                   //Initialized result to false

    for (i = 0; i < numero; i++)
    {
        //Asks user for input on student information.
        printf("\nEnter the information for student %d\n\n", i + 1);

        printf("\nEnter first name: ");
        scanf("%s", tempvalue);
        printf("%s", tempvalue);      
                                      //prints value to verify if tempvalue recieved
        strcpy(arr_student[i].first_name, tempvalue);
                                      //error begins with the arr_student being underlined

        printf("\nEnter last name: ");
        scanf("%s", tempvalue);
        strcpy(arr_student[i].last_name, tempvalue);

        printf("\nEnter student id: ");
        scanf("%s", tempvalue);
        strcpy(arr_student[i].id, tempvalue);

        printf("\nEnter student gpa: ");
        scanf("%s", tempvalue);
        strcpy(arr_student[i].gpa, tempvalue);

        printf("\nEnter student address: ");
        scanf("%s", tempvalue);
        strcpy(arr_student[i].address, tempvalue);

        printf("\nEnter student phone number: ");
        scanf("%s", tempvalue);
        strcpy(arr_student[i].phone_number, tempvalue);
    }

        printf("Enter the last name of the student you wish to examine data for: "); 
                                      //Asks input from the user for a name to search the data for
        scanf("%s", search); 


    for (i = 0; i < numero; i++)
    {
        result = strcmp(search, arr_student[i].last_name);
    }


    if (result == 0) //A match is found in the array
    {
        printf("Here is the data on the student: %s", search); 
        printf("First Name\t Last Name\t ID\t GPA\t Address\t Phone Number\n"); 
                                      //Prints out student information

        printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n",
        arr_student[i].first_name, arr_student[i].last_name, arr_student[i].id,
        arr_student[i].gpa, arr_student[i].address, arr_student[i].phone_number);
    }

    else
    {
        printf("The name you have entered is not in our system, please try again");
        return;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside: fix `return;` in `main()`.  Suggest `return -1`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the invalid `main()` definition from

```
int main(struct Student arr_student[numero])
{
```

to

```
int main(void) {
  struct Student arr_student[numero] = {0};
```

---

Use width limited input.

```
 char tempvalue[50];
 // scanf("%s", tempvalue);
 scanf("%49s", tempvalue);
```